# overview of functions, methods within a file

Tags: c++, ide

I would like to have an overview of all functions/methods/classes/namespaces defined within the currently open file (.cpp or .h).

Just like this is the case in VSCode and in Intellij (called "Outline" in one, and "Structure" in the other), with ability to quickly teleport to the definition:

[image]

I would prefer this feature to be implemented with LSP server instead of TAGS, but anything would be better than nothing.

Given the absence of standardized naming, I failed to google anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LSP - treemacs](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-treemacs) has what you want

Comment: wah looks amazing

Comment: This is a link-only answer, so it risks being deleted. Please summarize what's at the link that provides an answer.

Comment: It has the name of the package, and that the only thing that matters in that case.

Comment: Could you please provide some additional commentary in your answer to explain what the package does?  We'd like the answer to be self-contained.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the Speedbar stuff, and the `lsp-ui` package.